# Unit test: subscribe observable return undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I Work on an application using ionic and angular, and I faced this problem with unit test return undefined, but when the run the app everything is good.
my code :

auth.service.ts

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
return this.http
  .post<AuthResponseData>(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=${
      environment.firebaseAPIKey
    }`,
    // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-shorthand
    { email: email, password: password }
  ).pipe(tap(this.setUserData.bind(this)));}
```

auth.service.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

let server: AuthService;

describe('AuthService', () => {
beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
imports: [HttpClientTestingModule], 
providers: [AuthService]
}));
beforeEach(() =>  server = TestBed.get(AuthService));

it('fail ', done =>{
const e = 'INVALID_PASSWORD';
let result;
server.login('s@S.com', '987456').subscribe(
    good =>  {
    },
    errRes => {
      result = errRes.error.error.message;
    }
);
expect(result).toEqual(e);
done();
});
});
```

[karma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eEi5.jpg)

I hope to help me =(

Answer (score 0):

please include your code IN the question and not screen shots so people trying to help don't have to transcribe your code...

but move the test code INSIDE the error block so it executes after the observable emits:

```
errRes => {
   expect(errRes.error.error.message).toEqual(e);
   done();
}
```

Comment: I faced this problem => Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)